# plotting error_only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, plot

I want to plot a function and each time I got this error: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.
I want to plot my function over the w.

The code is :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
a = 10;
w = np.arange (0.001,10, 0.1)

function = (1/(np.pi*(w**2))+ np.pi)*abs(((-2*math.atan(a))*w)-(2*math.atanh(((w**2) + 1)/(-1*(w**2) + 2*(a**2) +1))*w)+ (np.pi*w) -(2*math.atanh(w/(a))))

plt.plot(w, function) 

plt.show()
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be better off using `numpy.arctan` and `numpy.arctanh` instead of the `math` equivalents, as they can work with arrays:

```
a = 10;
w = np.arange (0.001,10, 0.1)

function = (1/(np.pi*(w**2))+ np.pi)*abs(((-2*np.arctan(a))*w)-(2*np.arctanh(((w**2) + 1)/(-1*(w**2) + 2*(a**2) +1))*w)+ (np.pi*w) -(2*np.arctanh(w/(a))))

plt.plot(w, function) 

plt.show()
```

[image]